# Dangling quote character in TextView

Tags: android, text, textview

When I display quoted text in a textview, occasionally the wrapping will happen such that the final quote character (`"`) is wrapped but nothing else is. So I wind up with a dangling quote as the last line, which doesn't look right.

Is there some property to set to keep the text together in these instances? My only thought would be that the period at the end of a quote would get marked as whitespace or the end of a word and so the ui feels free to wrap what comes after.

Comment: Have you tried using layout_width="wrap_content"? Otherwise, maybe you should post your layout xml or Java code. Unfortunately I don't think there is any way to tune the wrapping algorithm other than having it display ellipsis or get truncated.

Answer (score 0):

Change the text font a half-size smaller or something similar to that. This could be an easy fix if not the best solution.

Comment: Unfortunately that just ends up making the quote wrap for other strings of different lengths.

Comment: Yes, which is why it's not the best solution.  You could however just make a special case such as "if(myQuoteThatNeedsDiffrentFont==True){ setFontSize("7.5"); }else{setFontSize("8");}  Or something of that nature.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem with dangling colon's in my TextViews, and this  bit of code stopped them from wrapping:

```
tv.setEllipsize(null);
tv.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
```

and my unverified stab at the equivalent xml:

```
android:ellipsize=0
android:singleLine="true"
```